# Use Twig's batch filter with conditional

Tags: templating, forloop, loop, batch

I am trying to make a grid of blocks using Twig. I have different types of blocks so I am using a conditional to test the block type and render different components per block type.

The problem I am having is I want to batch my blocks (columns) in twos so that I can have two blocks per row, so I can do `{% for row in entry.curatedContentBlocks|batch(2) if row.type == 'halfWidthBlock' %}`, add a row and then nest `{% for block in row %}` and add my block styles. This should work but when I try to test the block type with `row.type`, I get an error saying `Key "type" for array with keys "0, 1" does not exist.`. I'm thinking this is something to do with the `batch` filter returning an array.

I think the following code is the closest I've gotten, but I am still getting an error saying `Key "1" for array with keys "2, 3" does not exist.`. Here's the code:

```
{% for i, row in entry.curatedContentBlocks|batch(2) if row[i].type == 'halfWidthBlock' %}
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      {% for block in row %}
        <div class="text-center c6 med-c12 push-top-double">
          <div class="section fill-grey-light rounded">
            <div class="c12 grid-center">
              <h3>{{ block.titleText }}</h3>
              {% if block.ctaUrl|length and block.ctaText|length %}
                <a href="{{ block.ctaUrl }}" class="btn push-top">
                  {{ block.ctaText }}
                </a>
              {% endif %}
            </div> <!-- .c -->
          </div> <!-- .section -->
        </div> <!-- .c -->
      {% endfor %}
    </div> <!-- .row -->
  </div> <!-- .wrapper -->
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can test a conditional against a batch set like this. I think it's testing each batched set against the conditional instead of each item inside the batched sets which is what you're going for.

I would just create a new set of filtered matrix blocks and then batch the result.

```
{% set onlyHalfWidthBlocks = [] %}

{% for block in entry.curatedContentBlocks if block.type == 'halfWidthBlock' %}
  {% set onlyHalfWidthBlocks = onlyHalfWidthBlocks|merge([block]) %}
{% endfor %}

{% for row in onlyHalfWidthBlocks|batch(2) %}
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      {% for block in row %}
        {# ... block code here ... #}
      {% endfor %}
    </div> <!-- .row -->
  </div> <!-- .wrapper -->
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hey Sean, did this answer help?